Find a perfect matching
Ten students have taken an exam with ten problems. Each problem was solved by at least six students. Each student solved at least four problems. Show that it is possible to assign the problems, one to each student, so that each student is assigned a problem they have solved.
So I know that this is a bipartite graph and I am supposed to use Hall's theorem to show that there is a perfect matching so that each person can get one unique question that they have solved on the exam but I don't really understand how to use Hall's theorem considering it talks about a set.?
Halls Theorem states:
Let $G = (X \cup Y, E)$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $X$ and $Y$. There exists a perfect matching from $X$ to $Y$ if and only if for every subset $S \subseteq X$, the neighborhood of $S$, denoted by $N(S)$, satisfies
$|N(S)| \geq |S|$
In this case what is my set s? Should X be the people or the questions? Am I totally wrong doing Hall's theorem?

S is every subset of X, per the conditions of Hall's theorem. You need to show this for all $S$, not just a particular subset that you chose.

@CalvinLin how do I show that? I mean how do I even begin considering there is just way too many subsets so am I really supposed to go thru all of them?

I'm assuming you know how to apply Hall Marriage Theorem? If no, please go read up on it. If yes, how would you solve this version: 10 students, 10 problems. Each problem solved by exactly 5 students, each student solved exactly 5 problems. Show that a perfect matching exists.

I read about Hall's marriage theorem. To answer your question honeslty, I still don't know how I should go about solving the problem or your question.

The problem is symmetric for students and problems. Let $X$ be students, $Y$ be problems and $S \subseteq X$. If $0 < |S| \le 4$ then $|N(S)| \ge 4$ since every student solved at least $4$ problems. If $|S| \ge 5$ then $|X \setminus S| \le 5$ therefore $|N(S)| = 10 \ge |S|$ since every problem was solved by at least $6 > |X \setminus S|$ students and for every problem at least one student in $S$ has solved this problem.
